# How to add VAT validation Check

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, customer-address, vat, shipping-tax

Is it possible to add a VAT validation Check when user saves it (frontend)

Comment: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/tax/vat-validation-configure.html